# Create UIImage from default system icon with swift

Tags: ios, swift

How to create `UIImage` variable with **more** default system icon in swift?
I know how do this with `UIBuilder` in `storeboard` but I need to do programmatically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get reference to `UIImage` object of the system `UIBarButtonItem` objects. You can only create one from the predefined ones, but there is no way of obtaining the `UIImage` reference from them.
In storyboard you only set the desired type of the `UIBarButtonItem`, you don't actually select an `UIImage` object there.